# MemoryStream troubles

Tags: c#, .net, stream, memorystream

I'm having some trouble using a MemoryStream

We're using a 3rd party spreadsheet component (similar to excel), and I'm trying to save the data as html which they support through the `SaveHtml` method below. Seems very simple based on their documentation. Here is my code:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   this.ActiveSheet.SaveHtml(memoryStream);

   memoryStream.Position = 0;

   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
   {
       var htmlData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

I get an exception when I set the `memoryStream.Position = 0`:

`System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.`

A quick look at their SaveHtml method in Reflector shows the following relevant lines:

```
public void SaveHtml(Stream stream)
{
    StreamWriter writer = null;

    try
    {
        writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };

        writer.Write(str);
    }   
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing because the streamWriter is closed by their code, we're out of luck. Closing the streamWriter, closes the underlying Stream, right?

Any way to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: memoryStream.GetBuffer() should still work, imho

Comment: @user1096188: According to the source , it should! Post as answer. Good thing to remember, thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it works, so you can create another memory stream. No bytes are copied when extracting the buffer.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    this.ActiveSheet.SaveHtml(memoryStream);
    var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    using (var memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream2)) {
        var htmlData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Or you can roll out your own uncloseable MemoryStream and feed it to SaveHtml. This will also prevent disposing it, since Dispose just calls Close. Again, imho:

```
class MemoryStream2 : MemoryStream {
    public override void Close() { }
}
```

Comment: `.GetBuffer()` may return garbage bytes at the end. Use `.ToArray()` instead (which also works when the stream is closed). And instead of creating another memory stream, you can simply call `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray())`.

Comment: @user1096188: It would be better to override `Dispose`. Good and good idea on override never the less :) +1

Comment: @Allon Are you sure that there will be garbage? I tried to run `Console.WriteLine(new MemoryStream(1024 * 1024 * 1024).GetBuffer().Any(b => b != 0));` a few times and it always printed `false`...

Comment: @user1096188 The buffer is guaranteed to be zero-initialized.  I think Allon's point is that the buffer might be larger than the stream's contents.  "Extra" bytes could be non-zero if the stream was shortened at some point.  In this case, I doubt that is a risk.  Also, while I'm not sure how the StreamReader would handle extra zero bytes at the end, I suspect that handles them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative [memory stream](https://github.com/ImmortalGAD/ChunkedStream) implementation can be used in such context:

```
var stream = new ChunkedStream(pool, asOutputStreamOnDispose: true);

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write("hello world");
}

Assert.AreEqual(0, stream.Position);
Assert.AreEqual(ChunkedStreamState.ReadForward, stream.State);
Assert.AreEqual(3, pool.TotalAllocated);

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Assert.AreEqual("hello world", reader.ReadToEnd());
    Assert.AreEqual(0, pool.TotalAllocated);
}

Assert.AreEqual(ChunkedStreamState.Closed, stream.State);
```